# reuse of variadic arguments

Tags: c, variadic

I have a question regarding restarting variadic argument lists (`va_list`).
Basically I want to do something like this:

```
void someFunc(char* fmt, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(fmt, ap);
  otherFuncA(fmt, ap);
  // restart ap
  otherFuncB(fmt, ap);
  // restart ap
  ...
  va_end(ap);
  return;
}
```

Now my question is: How to restart `ap`?

Please note that this question is not related to C++ but C.

---

I found two possible solutions so far, but I would like to know which one is "correct" or "best practice".

**Solution 1: multiple `va_start()`**

With GCC7 I can replace the lines

```
// restart ap
```

in the example above by

```
va_end(ap);
va_start(fmt, ap);
```

to reset `ap` to the first argument.
However, I am not sure whether this is actually valid code or I am just lucky that some undefined behavior did not corrupt the result.

**Solution 2: `va_copy()`**

Another solution that works fine with GCC7 is to initialize several copies of `ap` using `va_copy()` like

```
void someFunc(char* fmt, ...) {
  va_list ap1, ap2;
  va_start(fmt, ap1);
  va_copy(ap2, ap1);
  otherFuncA(fmt, ap1);
  otherFuncB(fmt, ap2);
  va_end(ap1);
  va_end(ap2);
  return;
}
```

This is valid code (imo) but since there are multiple `va_list` instances now which need to be copied, it is much less efficient than the first solution.

---

So which solution is the best? Is it one of the two I mentioned above, or something completely different?

Comment: In your Solution 1, you must call `va_end` before calling `va_start` to restart the scan.

Comment: you are right - fixed it

Answer (score 6):

The `va_copy` way is valid: this is exactly what `va_copy` was made for. You say that *it is much less efficient than the first solution*. I do not really agree. First it is an implementation detail, but variadic argument list are commonly implemented in C as a pointer in the parameter stack, pointing on next argument to be retrieved by `va_arg`. So `va_copy` does not duplicate the argument list, but just a mere pointer.

But restarting the list by `va_arg` is valid too. Draft n1570 for C11 says at 7.16.1.3 The va_end macro (emphasize mine):

> ... The
>   va_end macro may modify ap so that it is no longer usable (**without being reinitialized
>   by the va_start** or va_copy macro).

My understanding is that it is legal to re-initialize the processing of the variadic arguments list with a new `va_arg` after the first `va_end`.

The difference between both ways, is that `va_copy` allows concurrent views of the same list, while reinitialization with `va_start` only allows sequential views (first is closed before second is opened).

My opinion is that the criteria for choice should not be performance, because the overhead of `va_copy` should be neglectible in decent implementations, but your real requirements: if you want only one view at a time on the list, stick to `va_arg` reinitialization, if concurrent lists allow cleaner of simpler processing, do use it with the help of `va_copy`.

Comment: Posix is even clearer, fwiw: ["Multiple traversals, each bracketed by `va_start() ... va_end()`, are possible."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdarg.h.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your helpful comments!

I tried several more approaches and I think I finally found two good solutions.

The first one is just solution 1 as described in my original question with the edit (thanks to rici).

The second one can be applied for more complex applications (as it turned out was required in my case). Let's start with the code:

```
void valistFunc(char* fmt, va_list ap) {
  va_list apcpy;
  for (/*all consecutive calls*/) {
    va_copy(apcpy, ap);
    otherFuncX(fmt, apcpy); // a different function for each iteration
    va_end(apcpy);
  }
  return;
}

void variadicFunc(char* fmt, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  valistFunc(fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return;
}
```

First of all, two functions are required if you have multiple methods like `variadicFunc` but you want to keep some of the logic in a single place (`valistFunc`).
However, you cannot pass on `...` as argument to subsequent functions, so you need to setup an according `va_list` object.
Then again, GCC complains (warns) if you try to use `va_start` in a function that does not take `...` as argument, why you cannot (or should not) use `va_start` in `valistFunc` (note: I don't know *why* GCC complains, I just assume there is some reason behind this behavior).
Instead, you need to instantiate a single additional copy `apcpy` that you can re-purpose as often as you like via `va_copy` and `va_end`.

I hope this might help someone else ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most important difference is that `va_copy` copies the exact current state of the primary used `va_list`. Therefore it **must** be called inbetween of `va_start` and `va_end` of the primary `va_list`, like so:

```
void someFunc(int arg1, ...) {
  va_list vl1, vl2;

  va_start(vl1, arg1);
  va_copy(vl2, vl1);

  // do stuff 1
  va_end(vl1);

  // do stuff 2
  va_end(vl2);
}
```

It therefore has a different usecase.
If copying an inbetween state of the primary va_list is not your goal, calling va_start a second time makes it more readable because it is more self explaining. It is also a matter of taste:

```
void someFunc(int arg1, ...) {
  va_list vl1, vl2;

  // do stuff 1
  va_start(vl1, arg1);
  va_end(vl1);

  // do stuff 2
  va_start(vl2, arg1);
  va_end(vl2);
}
```